# Problem with onEdit Google Sheets / AppsScript

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets, row, edit

Hope you are doing well!

I want to make the function I created, 'webScraping11,' run onEdit when columns AG, AS, or AU are modified but only in a specific row. For example, when we modify row 11, column AG, the functions should be executed, but only in that row (11).

I tried but without luck:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var hojaActual = e.source.getSheetByName("Duplicado");
  if (hojaActual && hojaActual.getName() === "Duplicado") {
    var celdaActiva = e.range;
    var filaActiva = celdaActiva.getRow();
    var colActiva = celdaActiva.getColumn();
    var valor = celdaActiva.getValue();

   
    if (colActiva === 33 || colActiva === 45 || colActiva === 47) {
      webScraping11(hojaActual, filaActiva);
    }
  }
}
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const idx = [33, 45, 47].indexOf(e.range.columnStart);
  if (sh.getName() == "Duplicado" && ~idx) {
    webScraping11(sh, e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

Note this function requires an onEdit event object.  You cannot run it from the script editor or call it unless you supply the event object

Comment: no working for me :(  Error: An unknown error has occurred. Try again later.

Comment: for some reason I had an extra character in the code

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I manage it:

```
function webScraping11(e) {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Duplicado");
      var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var editedRow = e.range.getRow();
    
    
       { // Empezamos desde la fila 3
        try {
        if (editedRow >= 4) {
          var i = editedRow - 1;
          var agValue = data[i][32]; // Columna AG (índice 31)
          var ahValue = data[i][43]; // Columna AH (índice 32)
          var aiValue = data[i][45]; // Columna AI (índice 33)
```